# How to select the prompt from a list of strings?

Tags: python, prompt

I have searched but could not fond an answer. 
So i have

```
Mood = raw_input("How are you?")
```

How do I make it so it picks the raw question from a list so it could be 'how are you' are 'what are you feeling'

Comment: No because its a input

Comment: But you don't have problem with input, you have problem with picking question from the list, and you should name your question accordingly.

Comment: Please don't write title as sequences of tags. `python - raw_input` doesn't mean anything. Use complete English sentences. 
Also there's already the python tag in the question, so you don't have to mention `python` in the title, and `raw_input` is completely irrelevant to what you want to achieve (you can replace it with anything and the question doesn't change).

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
Mood = raw_input(random.choice(['how are you?', 'what are you feeling?']))
```

Answer (score 0):

just index into the list

```
    ques = ['how are you?', 'what are you feeling?']

    ans = raw_input(ques[0])
```